# How can I transfer followers from Wordpress.com to a self-hosted Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting, rss, subscription, community

Recently, I performed a domain migration from a wordpress.com domain to a self-hosted solution.  The primary complaint was the loss of followers gained through Wordpress ( http://marygoround.me/2012/02/18/to-all-my-current-wordpress-followers/ )

I don't see any plugins that Automattic has released to allow similar functionality to "Subscribe" and "Like" content on self-hosted blogs, so it's feeling more and more like a closed garden.

What can I do to make sure this audience is preserved after the migration?

Answer (score 2):

Self-hosted blogs use RSS for subscriptions.

As far as "liking" goes, that only makes sense within the quasi-social-network environment of WordPress.com.

Answer (score 2):

You cam use http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jetpack/ which is by Automattic  and has the desired Subscribe/follow functionallty.

Comment: Thanks, but installing Jetback (and purchasing the domain redirect from Wordpress.com) doesn't seem to pull in the subscribers at the original URL.

Answer (score 1):

[According to Tim Moore](http://jetpack.me/2012/01/17/how-to-view-your-email-subscribers/comment-page-1/#comment-2018), Code Wrangler at Automattic (the company behind WordPress):

> For WordPress.com users who migrate their WordPress.com blog to
>   WordPress.org with [Jetpack](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jetpack/) installed, we have tools to assist you.
>   Please contact Support (`support at jetpack.me`) with your
>   WordPress.com address and your new Jetpack-enabled address. Note that
>   this is a permanent transfer.

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while, but I think you're referring to people who subscribed to receive an email when a new post is added to your RSS feed. (If you're talking about subscribing to the RSS feed with a feed reader, then as long as the new site creates posts in the same format as the old one (http://domain name/year/month/date/post) I would think there should be no issue that when a URL is resolved it points to the new page.)

If email *is* the problem, I found this tip: http://www.redbridgenet.com/wordpress/how-to-export-subscribers-from-wordpress-com/ (I Googled "export wordpress.com email subscribers"). If it's not ... well, then not sure I understand what specifically is not happening. There are lost of plugins out there for connecting up with social networks. I use http://share-and-follow.com/wordpress-plugin/.